# Send push notifications to a user who is not active for a week in Unity and Firebase

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a game with Unity. I use Firebase SDK for analytics and messaging. The messaging works fine, but I want to send a notification to a user that is not active for a week. I did not see a option like this in Firebase SDK, do I need to do this in Unity from a script ? Is it so, is there any tutorials? So, how can I this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use both unity scripts and firebase functions to do it. Create a new child in your users database that contains a date with the last login, and each time a user logs in, update it (you can do this with an unity script). In your firebase function, get the last login date for every user and if it's longer than a week, send a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt using this Github repository, the way I read the license terms under the "MIT" section it seems to be open source.

https://github.com/Agasper/unity-android-notifications

Take a look.

Also for iOS if you need that later, there is the LocalNotification.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.LocalNotification.html

I am unaware of Unity having a similar function for Android, but if you come across it, do let me know in the comment section below.